# Combinations and probability

Tags: combinations, permutation, probability, discrete-mathematics

So I'm having trouble with these two problems, and have kind of started them but not sure if I'm on the correct track. (I'm using the combination and permutation formulas)

```
Problem 1: "A group of students contains five men and six women."
"I go to the store to buy hats for the eleven students. Hats come in four colors: red, blue,
green, and yellow. How many different ways can I buy the hats, if I have to buy at least one hat
each color?"
```

This is how I'm going about the problem:

Total ways buy hats with 1 of each color = Total ways of buying hats - Total ways of buying only 3 different kind of hats - Total ways of buying only 2 different kind of hats - Total ways of buying only 1 kind of hat

Total ways of buying hats repetition C(4, 11): **!(4 + 11 - 1)/!11(4-1)!**

Total ways of buying 3 hats: 11-combinations of buying 3 hats, C(3, 11),  * 3-combinations of 4 hats, C(4,3):
**(!(3 + 11 - 1)/!11(3-1)!) * (!4/!3(4-3)!)**

.... and so on for 2 hats and 1 hats.

Is this correct? Thinking about it logically, shouldn't the difference of that be the answer?

Sorry if that's hard to understand my work, it was the best I could put it in normal format. But pretty much what I'm doing is getting the total choices by repetitive C(4, 11), and then subtracting the total choices of 3, 2, and 1 hats chosen.
To find those total choices I do the
the repetitive C(X,11) * non-repetitive C(4, X) for x-values 3,2,1

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your work is kinda correct but it is not correct. The principle you are working with is called [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). It is a very powerful tool to solve discrete mathematics problem.

But about your mistake. You said :

> Total ways buy hats with 1 of each color = Total ways of buying hats -
>   Total ways of buying only 3 different kind of hats - Total ways of
>   buying only 2 different kind of hats - Total ways of buying only 1
>   kind of hat

but it is not correct, the correct way is :

> Total ways buy hats with 1 of each color = Total ways of buying 4 hats -
>   Total ways of buying only 3 different kind of hats + Total ways of
>   buying only 2 different kind of hats - Total ways of buying only 1
>   kind of hat

also this is not correct :

```
Total ways of buying hats repetition C(4, 11): !(4 + 11 - 1)/!11(4-1)!
```

for the correct answer consider that, every student have 4 choice for his/her hat, so:

**Total ways of buying hats : 4<sup>11</sup>**.

and for 3 hats it is :

**Total ways of buying hats : C(3,4) * 3<sup>11</sup>**.

and so on ...

so the final answer is :

**4<sup>11</sup> - C(3,4) * 3<sup>11</sup> + C(2,4) * 2<sup>11</sup> - C(1,4) * 1<sup>11</sup>**

Comment: Excuse me if I'm incorrect, but I have doubts about you total ways of buying hats. Why is it 4^11? You used the product rule for each hat, but the product rule is for separate tasks. In this problem, we are looking at the different total purchases. We aren't looking at all the different possibilities, but the number of different purchases at the end. Ie. 4 blue, 4 red, 2 green, 1 yellow. As you have it, I'm pretty sure it will account for those multiple times, just because of a different purchase order

Comment: @ComputerDope they are separate, when you just want to buy anyone a hat, it is 4^11, but for meeting your conditions, there is rest of my solution.

Comment: I don't understand. So let's say we had only 2 possible colors, red and blue. From your answer, that means there will be 2^11 different ways. In reality the only ways would be (0 red, 11 blue), (1 red, 10 blue), (2 red, 9 blue)...(9 red, 2 blue), (10 red, 1 blue), (11 red, 0 blue). There are 12 different ways of buying 11 hats of 2 colors (same as C(2,11)). 2^11 is 2048 which is taking each specific purchase into consideration

Comment: @ComputerDope I though students are different, if student are same and it doesnt matter, so I have to change my answer. Also C(2,11) = 55 not 12!

Comment: I sort of understand what youre saying now. But it seems ridiculous that hes making individual purchases rather than buying all at once.

Comment: students are different, what do you mean? And C(N,R) for repetitive is (N+R-1)!/!R(N-1)! so C(2,11) = !12/!11 = 12

Comment: @ComputerDope it is not ridiculous, if student are the same, problem could simply say we want to buy 11 hats!

Comment: @ComputerDope Also your main mistake was with inclusion-exclusion principle :)